# displaying images in php/html

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to set  the `src` of an image to a value in a database but it doesnt seem to be working.. here's the lines in question,

```
<?php
echo "  $date<br/>"?>
        <img src="<?phpecho $image;?>"/><br/>
        <?php echo"$text

    ";   
?>
```

and the error:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a6349675/public_html/Blog.php on line 54`

Answer (score 2):

Need a space between phpecho:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>"/><br/>
```

Also remove the quotes from the last echo:

```
<?php echo $text; ?>
```

Lol, and the first echo as well.

```
echo  $date; ?><\br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find yourself a good editor, then it would of shown the syntax error in your code.

Also 99% of the time having tidy code will make it easier to spot errors.

```
<?php echo $date."<br/>"; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>"/><br/>
<?php echo $text; ?>
```

or simply

```
<?php 
echo $date.'<br/>',
     '<img src="'.$image.'"/><br/>',
     $text;
?>
```